# Grails: how to test association?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm sure this question has been answered before but I couldn't find it in the documentation or elsewhere.
How can I (unit?) test the association in a grails domain model class?

For example, if I have the following class:

```
class StudentClass {

    static hasMany = [students: Student]

    static mapping = {
        students cascade: "none"
    }
}

class Student {
    String name

    static belongsTo = [studentClass: StudentClass]

}
```

How can I test 'hasMany' and its cascading?

edit:

In other words I want to test the effects of adding this configuration to my model, to make sure it satisfies my needs.

For example I'd like to be able to do something like (assuming I understood the doc on associations ; feel free to change it to a better test or to fix it if I made mistakes)

```
def sc = new StudentClass().save()

new Student(studentClass: sc, name: 'name1').save()
assert StudentClass.count() == 1
assert StudentClass.get(1).students.size() == 1
assert StudentClass.get(1).get(0).name == 'name'

StudentClass.delete(1)
assert Student.count() == 1
```

Thanks

Comment: What in particular do you want to test?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Well for example I want to test that there is no cascading. And by that I do not mean testing whether cascading is present, but rather testing whether the effects of cascading are present. In other words, testing that adding cascade: 'none' was indeed what I wanted to do. Similarly for 'hasMany'.

Comment: I've edited my question to give an exemple

Comment: There isn't much value in testing that the framework is working as expected - I prefer to work under the assumption that the framework will work correctly and only test the code I have written.

Comment: @doelleri I do understand that, but since i'm not familiar with the framework that much, I thought this test would serve me as some kind of documentation of what those configurations imply to my class. Also, it somehow tests my code though, since I've added 'hasMany' and 'none' and such. Anyhow, is this possible? Is it a unit test, or another kind of test?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown  I'm actually mainly unsure whether it's a unit test or something else, though I wouldn't mind a full example (testing 'hasMany' and 'belongsTo' and 'cascade', similar to what I've tried in my edit)

Comment: @Mfx yes, this is not something that should be tested with unit test and is quite easy to test with and integration test (since its boots up your database), your example code should actually test the cascading already as it is.

Comment: @TuomasValtonen yeah I had a feeling this was an Integration test, though I wasn't sure... So what would that integration test look like? I haven't made any...

Comment: @doelleri maybe you can help?

Comment: https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/testing.html#integrationTesting

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I have tried to understand how the cascade updating and deleting works in GORM and come across your question. After encountering the problem of unit test for testing one-to-many relationship, I made a question on Grails' slack channel and one suggested we can create an integration test as cascading might not be designed to run with unit tests.

Let's create domain classes as below.

**SchoolClass.groovy**

```
package com.itersdesktop.javatechs.grails.gorm

class SchoolClass implements Serializable{
    // for example: Class 1 or Owl class
    String name
    // year 1, year 2, etc.
    Integer year
    // for example: 2018-2019
    String schoolYear
    // there are at least two teachers: main and assistant
    static hasMany = [teachers: SchoolTeacher, pupils: Pupil]

    static mapping = {
        teachers cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
        pupils cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
    }

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

**SchoolTeacher.groovy**

```
package com.itersdesktop.javatechs.grails.gorm

class SchoolTeacher implements Serializable {
    String name

    static belongsTo = [schoolClass: SchoolClass]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

**Pupil.class**

```
package com.itersdesktop.javatechs.grails.gorm

class Pupil implements Serializable {
    String name
    static belongsTo = [schoolClass: SchoolClass]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

As you can see, `SchoolClass` has `teachers` and `pupils` properties that are setup updating and deleting cascading on it. What we want to verify is that pupils will be automatically removed as long as the school class instance is destroyed. To do so, I made a unit test and an integration test named `SchoolClassSpec.groovy` and `SchoolClassItSpec` respectively.
[image]

**SchoolClassSpec.groovy**

```
package com.itersdesktop.javatechs.grails.gorm

import grails.testing.gorm.DomainUnitTest
import spock.lang.Specification

class SchoolClassSpec extends Specification implements DomainUnitTest<SchoolClass> {
    SchoolClass schoolClass
    Pupil p

    void setupData() {
        schoolClass = new SchoolClass(name: "Owl class", year: 2, schoolYear: "2017-2018")
        p = new Pupil(name: "Tony Nguyen")
        schoolClass.addToPupils(p)
    }

    void "test SchoolClass domain"() {
        given: "let's create a school class and a pupil"
        setupData()
        when: "save the school class"
        schoolClass.save()
        then: "we also save the pupil because we set cascade on SchoolClass"
        1 == SchoolClass.count
        1 == Pupil.count
        when: "get the school class and the pupil back"
        p = Pupil.get(1)
        schoolClass = SchoolClass.get(1)
        then: "we hope the returned values match with the inputs"
        p.name == "Tony Nguyen"
        schoolClass.name == "Owl class"
        schoolClass.schoolYear == "2017-2018"
        when: "let's delete the school class"
        schoolClass.delete(flush: true)
        then: "we hope the pupil will be deleted as well"
        0 == SchoolClass.count
        1 == Pupil.count
    }
}
```

Notes: The last line `1 == Pupil.count` is because if we test `0 == Pupil.count`, the test will be failed. The test report generated by [Spock-Reports](https://sites.google.com/a/athaydes.com/renato-athaydes/posts/spock-reports-greattestreportsthatyouactuallywanttoread) plugin looks like the following screenshot.
[image]

Let's play the same code above but in an integration test as described below.

**SchoolClassItSpec.groovy**

```
package com.itersdesktop.javatechs.grails.gorm

import grails.testing.mixin.integration.Integration
import grails.transaction.Rollback
import spock.lang.Specification

@Integration
@Rollback
class SchoolClassItSpec extends Specification {
    SchoolClass schoolClass
    Pupil p

    void setupData() {
        schoolClass = new SchoolClass(name: "Owl class", year: 2, schoolYear: "2017-2018")
        p = new Pupil(name: "Tony Nguyen")
        schoolClass.addToPupils(p)
    }

    void "test SchoolClass domain"() {
        given: "let's create a school class and a pupil"
        /*SchoolClass schoolClass = new SchoolClass(name: "Owl class", year: 2, schoolYear: "2017-2018")
        Pupil p = new Pupil(name: "Tony Nguyen")
        schoolClass.addToPupils(p)*/
        setupData()
        when: "save the school class"
        schoolClass.save()
        then: "we also save the pupil because we set cascade on SchoolClass"
        1 == SchoolClass.count
        1 == Pupil.count
        when: "get the school class and the pupil back"
        p = Pupil.get(1)
        schoolClass = SchoolClass.get(1)
        then: "we hope the returned values match with the inputs"
        p.name == "Tony Nguyen"
        schoolClass.name == "Owl class"
        schoolClass.schoolYear == "2017-2018"
        when: "let's delete the school class"
        schoolClass.delete(flush: true)
        then: "we hope the pupil will be deleted as well"
        0 == SchoolClass.count
        0 == Pupil.count
    }
}
```

Run this integration test, I got the report captured the screenshot as below.
[image]

**Discussions**
What we can draw conclusions from the tests are:

- The integration test works for cascading delete operation.
- When we delete a school class instance that contains a list of pupils or has a list of responsible teachers, the pupils and teachers of the school class will be got rid of though we don't call delete operations explicitly on each element of these lists. I think this test illustrates how cascading works in relational databases.

I pushed [the project to my bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/itersdesktop/gorm-demo-relationships/src). Feel free to clone and test it.

Comment: I haven't had time to read carefully your answer yet. But I just wanted by this comment to say thank you, it really sounds like an awesome answer. I'm sure I'll have questions when I've fully read it.

Comment: You're very welcome! I have updated my recommended answer by adding source code in bitbucket if you want to test straightaway.